# ExecuteScript for JavaScript on CoreWebView2(from Delphi) does not work after first time of run until refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, delphi, microsoft-edge

I'm using CoreWebView2(Microsoft Edge) from Delphi 11 to Execute JavaScripts on web pages. The problem is that I execute script without any problem for the first time. for example the script shown below:

```
let x = 0;
alert("Hello");
```

When just execute "alert" command, it works without any problem for countless times of run. But when you run any other command lines except "alert" command, the second run of ExecuteScript fails with no errors but doesn't respond.

The whole code is like shown below:

```
procedure TBrowserFrame.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
s: string;
begin
  s:= 'let x = 0;alert("uu");';
  WVBrowser1.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScript(s,0,WVBrowser1);
end;
```

Comment: How can you know if you're not even checking the [function's `Boolean` result](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi/blob/main/source/uWVCoreWebView2.pas#L999)?

Comment: the sample code must show an alert dialog saying "uu". in first click of button it shows alert dialog but in second, third , ... run it doesn't show the alert dialog too.

in the first and second run of the code, the ExecuteScript command returns True.

Comment: i can only guess: is your first exceuteScript call not finished? (is another call necessary to signal: script is finished?)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Removing the expression "let" solved the problem. if you want to execute script more than one time without refreshing the page, it is necessary to write in this way:

```
x = 0;
alert("Hello");
```

Comment: In a more general sense, what you did was to correct an error in your Javascript code.  You can't redeclare a variable declared with let.